# MySQL: create a function but it already exists

Tags: mysql, mysql-function

MySQL Server version: 5.1.73 Source distribution.

I can't create a *function*, it is still exists after I drop it.

Drop the function first:

> ```
> mysql> drop function if exists `xapps_f20160817`;
> Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
>
> mysql> show warnings;
> +-------+------+-----------------------------------------+
> | Level | Code | Message                                 |
> +-------+------+-----------------------------------------+
> | Note  | 1305 | FUNCTION xapps_f20160817 does not exist |
> +-------+------+-----------------------------------------+
> 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
> ```

But It still alive when I create it again.

> ```
> mysql> create function `xapps_f20160817`(
>     -> `_time` varchar(30),
>     -> `_rpid` varchar(10),
>     -> `_mvsz` varchar(10),
>     -> `_rvsz` varchar(10),
>     -> `_ncpu` varchar(10),
>     -> `_rcpu` varchar(10),
>     -> `_appn` varchar(64)
>     -> )  RETURNS BIGINT READS SQL DATA
>     -> BEGIN
>     -> insert into `20160817`(time, rpid, mvsz, rvsz, ncpu, rcpu, appn)
>     -> values(_time, _rpid, _mvsz, _rvsz, _ncpu, _rcpu, _appn);
>     -> RETURN LAST_INSERT_ID();
>     -> END
> ERROR 1304 (42000): FUNCTION xapps_f20160817 already exists
> ```

Try to use:

> ```
> mysql> select xapps_f20160817('100','100','100','100','100','100','100');$$
> ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION xapps_db.xapps_f20160817 does not exist
> ```

Try to find it from function list:

> ```
> mysql> show function status where name='xapps_f20160817';$$
> Empty set (0.00 sec)
> ```

Try to drop it, but it does not exist:

> ```
> mysql> drop function if exists `xapps_f20160817`;$$
> Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
>
> mysql> show warnings;$$
> +-------+------+-----------------------------------------+
> | Level | Code | Message                                 |
> +-------+------+-----------------------------------------+
> | Note  | 1305 | FUNCTION xapps_f20160817 does not exist |
> +-------+------+-----------------------------------------+
> 1 row in set (0.01 sec)
> ```

Is it bug of MySQL? How to remove this function correctly?

Comment: try to create function with dbname.functionname

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have a selected db from `use mydbname;`

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS myfunc789a;
DELIMITER $$
create function myfunc789a
(   theI INT
)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    RETURN theI*7;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

select myfunc789a(8);
```

DELIMITER is used only in some client tools. Not phpmyadmin.

avec backticks, no problem 5.6 5.7:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `myfunc789a`;
DELIMITER $$
create function `myfunc789a`
(   theI INT
)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    RETURN theI*7;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

select `myfunc789a`(8);
```

### [`Bug # 16303`](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=16303):

[image]

Comment: So placing the function name in backticks is not a problem then?

Comment: Probably the typical problem of *I don't have your exact environment to test it in*

Comment: I upvotee you.  I don't use it heavily on the weekends, though I try to get a few answers in.  Yeah, I have no life.

Comment: This strange situations are rarely occurred. Syntax of examples are already used from my server, there are no problem, of course database is selected before.

Comment: @J.H we aren't sitting there and how are we to know :p

Comment: Then there is this from that era https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=17012

Comment: @Drew Thanks your link of bug give a clue for workaround it.

Comment: Sorry you endured this. Hopefully an upgrade in the near future. I can't stand being on 5.6. Can't even enjoy the new json.